# Markdown preview is inconsistent with actual rendering when using blockquotes inside a list

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-preview

On Meta Islam I posted [this question](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/856/3487), which seemed perfect in the preview below the edit box.

> [image]

But when I posted the question I got something *partially* different:

> [image]

Comment: My best guess is the weird syntax. Have you tried removing the line-breaks between the numbers and the blockquote starts, e.g. just use `1. > Some text` all on the same line?

Comment: @animuson It does work, [*tested result*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209649/221866). Problem was when I added the second item and quoted it using the `ctrl-o` `ctrl-q` sequence, the item got nested. Removing the new line before the quote (`>`) got it fixed it.